# Select matching substring

Tags: json, jq

Given the following ideal2.json

```
[
    {
    "url": "/classroom-videos/lesson1/sublesson1/video",
        "data": {
            "fieldset": "lesson-video-overview",
            "title": "5th Grade Math - Interpreting Fractions",
        },
        "order": 4
    },
    {
    "url": "/classroom-videos/lesson1/sublesson2/video",
        "data": {
            "fieldset": "lesson-video-clip-single",
            "title": "Post-Lesson Debrief Part 5",
        },
        "order": 14
    },
    {
        "url" : "about-us",
        "data": {
            "fieldset": "lesson-video-clip-single",
            "title": "Lesson Part 2B",
        },
        "order": 6
    }
]
```

I want to extract only the items where the url starts with `/classroom-videos/`

Ideally my output would look like this:

```
[
    {
    "url": "/classroom-videos/lesson1/sublesson1/video",
        "data": {
            "fieldset": "lesson-video-overview",
            "title": "5th Grade Math - Interpreting Fractions",
        },
        "order": 4
    },
    {
    "url": "/classroom-videos/lesson1/sublesson2/video",
        "data": {
            "fieldset": "lesson-video-clip-single",
            "title": "Post-Lesson Debrief Part 5",
        },
        "order": 14
    }
]
```

I tried lots of variations with no luck:
e.g.
`select(.url | contains("yomama"))` produces 
jq: error (at :47): Cannot index array with string "url"
exit status 5

`.[].url` produces a nice list of all the urls

Comment: @peak I tried so many variations that my mind is kinda of spinning. I can certainly post lots of attempts if that helps clarify what I am trying to do.

Comment: Why not take a minute to look at the answers to your other SO question, and then look at the relevant sections of the jq tutorial and reference manual.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @peak.  I've been hammering at this for quite some time through the manuals and google and SO.  I think I just figured it out.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this might do the trick:

`jq '.[] | select(.url |test("classroom-videos"))'`

Comment: The original question specified "url starts with", so `startswith(...)` or `test("^...")` would be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks @peak, that is very kind of you to add the matching substring.  I'm sure that will help others trying to solve similar problems